# How to build interdependent forms in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a rails app and am a rails newbie. I have two models - cab operators and cabs, which are related with each other as:

```
class Cab < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :operator
end
```

There is also a third model Driver, and I am creating a form to edit drivers employed by an operator. One of the fields of the form allows the user to choose amongst the Opertors, as:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :operator_id, "Operator Name" %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:operator_id, Operator.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

The form also contains a field to choose from the cabs, as:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cab_id, "Cab Number" %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:cab_id, Cab.all, :id, :number) %>
</div>
```

However, I want to display only those cabs through the above field that are assigned to the operator chosen from the first collection_select. Is this possible? How?

EDIT: The form is being generated for the Driver object, as:

```
<%= form_for(@driver) do |f| %>
```

Also, Driver is related to Cabs as follows:

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :operator
    belongs_to :cab
end
```

Comment: For which object you're building the form? Can you also post the associations in operator and driver classes as well?

Comment: So, this won't work for a new driver. Also, if you're editing a driver why will you display all operators instead of @driver's operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are wanting to do nested forms.  There will be several elements including proper Rails model setup, controller and AJAX.

Check out this rails cast, should get you close to what you are needing.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You can make a parent form and others shall be its child forms. This means that you will inherit a form from the parent form which will make your forms interdependent.

Comment: Thanks Arsalan KB, but I need to make this happen in real time, i.e. as soon as I select the Operator from the first collection_select, it should populate all the cabs assigned to that Operator through the second collection_select

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a form and as soon as you select the operator you can show the form.